# Mac "VoiceOver" accessing the content beneath the modal box

Tags: javascript, html, macos, accessibility, voiceover

Even thought the tab navigation is limited to the modal box, Mac "VoiceOver" still accessing the content beneath the modal box. NVDA doesn't have this issue. Below link is from W3. The example in this page also has the issue.

[Modal Dialog Example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html)

I don't know, whether the functionality is default or real issue. Can somebody confirm?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is an ongoing issue (a VoiceOver bug / design decision) that despite many attempted hacks and workarounds appears to be very difficult to solve effectively.

What i eventually did to solve this that works 100% of the time was to apply `aria-hidden="true"` to the main content and then hold the modal outside of the main content.

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="your-content" aria-hidden="true">
        //main content, hidden when modal is opened via aria-hidden.
        //This should be the main container for the page that holds EVERYTHING else other than your modal
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
        //modal content, with all of your existing constraints in place to stop tabbing outside etc.   
    </div>
</section>
```